# Kann »Hand« sächlich sein?

Tags: single-word-request, gender

Zu einem Produkt habe ich den folgenden Bericht gefunden:

> Die Einrichtung war kompliziert, da auch das Hand sehr schmal ist.

Fünf Wörterbücher bestätigen, *Hand* sei weiblich. Kann »Hand« sächlich sein?

---

<sup>Soll es um einen Typo gehen, so würde ich die Frage löschen.</sup>

Comment: Vielleicht ein Schreibfehler, und gemeint war "das Handbuch"?

Comment: Oh ja. Das hätte ich erraten sollen. Die Frage ergäbe nun bessern Sinn, hätte ich gefragt, ob es geläufig ist, Handbuch durch *Hand* abzukürzen. Also ihr könnt gerne die Frage schließen, habe ich selber dafür gewählt.

Comment: Nein, die Abkürzung ist auch nicht geläufig. Außerdem ist die Formulierung dann immer noch ungünstig gewählt, denn es ist ja nicht die Schuld des dünnen oder schmalen Handbuchs, dass die Einrichtung kompliziert war. Aber mach Dir keine Sorgen, die allermeisten Muttersprachler wären mit dem Satz ebenso aufgeschmissen.

Comment: @c.p. Du hättest bei der close-reason nicht so streng mit Dir sein müssen ;-) Außerdem solltest Du die Frage auch einfach selbst löschen können. Bei meinen sehe ich jedenfalls einen delete-Link.

Comment: @Matthias: Du kannst eigene Fragen nur selbst löschen, wenn sie keine positive bewertete Antwort haben.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an erroneous source that is not of general interest.

Comment: Ich kann die vielleicht löschen, es erscheint aber eine bedrohende Abmahnung! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nein. Wobei ich jetzt keine Quelle habe, die über ein Online-Wörterbuch hinausgehen würde.

Aber selbst wenn da stünde "da auch die Hand sehr schmal ist", ergibt das für mich keinen Sinn. Geht es Dir auch um das Verständnis, oder reicht Dir die Auskunft, dass "Hand" immer weiblich ist? Zum Verständnis müsstest Du etwas mehr Kontext (welches Produkt, was für eine Einrichtung etc.) liefern.

Comment: Es war ein Stereoanlage. Daher könnte es um das Handbuch gehen.

Comment: @c.p. Ich glaube an einen Übersetzungsfehler, der darauf basiert, dass [_manual_ als vorgestelltes Adjektiv oft mit einem Kompositum, das mit _Hand..._ beginnt, übersetzt werden kann](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=Hand...&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on). Offenbar hat das Übersetzungsprogramm erkannt, dass es sich hierbei nicht um das feminine Wort _Hand_ handelt, sondern dass das Genus vom zweiten (hier fehlenden) Teil des Kompositums bestimmt wird.